# Display content on a page only

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I tried to use this code to display only a specific page #content in Wordpress but not working...

```
body.page-id-2 .masthead-fixed .site-main {
display: none;
}
```

This is the site:

http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp/

I searched the internet and I saw examples can do that but I do not work

I was wrong somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.page-id-2` and `.masthead-fixed` are in the same level in your html, so you have to make it like this:

```
body.page-id-2.masthead-fixed .site-main {
    display: none;
}
```

or completely remove `.masthead-fixed` selector :

```
body.page-id-2 .site-main {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide all this elements?

```
body.page-id-2, 
.masthead-fixed, 
.site-main {
    display: none;
}
```